# Bootstrap Dynamic Layout Change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, dynamic

I am currently using bootstrap on a website which is displaying an ecommerce store. 
The current layout is 3 columns of items within 4 rows, but I am wanting to implement a button which will change it to 2 columns.
I have done so, however the code seems to be causing some issues in that the layout changes to

> Two Items
>   One Item
>   Two Items
>   One Item

Each one Item row has a large area of white space where an item could go.

The Code below shows one "Row" which is in the three column layout. I have used javascript which changes the class 'col-sm-4' to 'col-sm-6'. Where is my mistake here?

```
    <div class="row"><!-- row 2 -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 product-category-display">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/img/products/women/jackets_coats/raina_parka.png" class="product-image">
        </div>
        <div class="row product-status">
            <span class="products-status-sale">Sale</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="product-name col-sm-12"<p>Raina Waterproof Parka</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row product-price">
            <span>£99.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 product-category-display">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/img/products/women/jackets_coats/april_jacket.png" class="product-image">
        </div>
        <div class="row product-status">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p class="product-name col-sm-12">April Waterproof Front Pocket Jacket</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row product-price">
            <span>£99.95</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 product-category-display">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="assets/img/products/women/jackets_coats/free_delivery.png" class="product-image">
        </div>
        <div class="row product-status">
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row product-price">
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end row 2 -->
```

Comment: First, I think you should do like this to separate different row. `<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"></div><div class="col-sm-12"></div></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The columns should only add upto 12. When you change 4 to 6 its becomes 18.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4"></div><div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the best way to swap to a 2 column grid? As I feel it has something to do with the 'Rows' I have in my code

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just had to remove all of the rows and tweak the JS to add the class